# UIWebView HTML font size issue

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I display HTML content in UIWebView in my one of the iPhone application.

Check below 2 images :

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68104003/Screen%20Shot%202013-05-11%20at%2011.47.02%20AM.png
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68104003/Screen%20Shot%202013-05-11%20at%2011.47.28%20AM.png

I have used the same HTML code for both titles but it display the different font size on the screen.

Below is the HTML code i have used :

```
<span style="font-size:19px;"><strong><span style="font-family:times new roman,times,serif;">4.6&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum is simply</span></strong></span></br>

<span style="font-size:19px;"><strong><span style="font-family:times new roman,times,serif;">4.4&nbsp;&nbsp;Type and Scrambled</span></strong></span></br>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=5.0\" />
```

added this to the html string 
worked for me
change the initial scale as required

Answer (score 1):

i used below code to fix font size and text alignment problem. Hope it will help for you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   [super viewDidLoad];
currentTextSize = 100;
webview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
webview.delegate=self;
webview.scalesPageToFit=YES;
webview.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
NSString *varMySheet = @"var mySheet = document.styleSheets[0];";
NSString *addCSSRule =  @"function addCSSRule(selector, newRule) {"
"if (mySheet.addRule) {"
"mySheet.addRule(selector, newRule);"                               // For Internet Explorer
"} else {"
"ruleIndex = mySheet.cssRules.length;"
"mySheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + newRule + ';}', ruleIndex);"   // For Firefox, Chrome, etc.
"}"
"}";
 NSString *insertRule2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('p', 'text-align: justify;')"];
NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding: 0px; height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap: 0px;')", webView.frame.size.height];

NSString *setTextSizeRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('body', '-webkit-text-size-adjust: %d%%;')", currentTextSize];
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:varMySheet];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:addCSSRule];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule2];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setTextSizeRule];}
```

Comment: From where i can i get "currentTextSize"?

Comment: 100 return actual html font size.

Comment: Thanks, I had a similar problem and this put me on the right track, I just set -webkit-text-size-adjust to none.

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView supports zooming, and that naturally affects the size of the type. It's likely that when you saw the larger type, you were just zoomed in further, perhaps because the widths of the two pages is different.

Comment: when we zoom the definitely it will affect the size but when i don't zoom the page then also it display the different font size. It's a book app so i have used UIPageViewController in which i have display the UIWebView ao the page width is same.

Comment: @Reena I understand that the web views may be the same, but the page width as determined by the HTML is probably different. UIWebView will try to fit the entire HTML page, so if you've got some wide content on one page and not on the other, text on the page with the wider content will appear smaller.